# Regular expression that validate username like

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that matches string that contain

1. alphanumeric value
2. must start with alphabetic character
3. no special character allowed
4. and min length 5 char and max 20.

   ```
   ^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+$
   ```

I have generated many but above is working for me only one thing remain in above expression that is length validation.

Comment: `str.length >=5 && str.length <=20`

Comment: consider separating the regex to the 4 requirement, so that you can notify the user what's wrong with his input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,19}$
```

That specifies the min/max length of the latter half.

Comment: sorry it allow spaces after 5 or more letters

Comment: Forgot the $ - just added - sorry